# Is there always a bijection between the subspaces of dimension m and codimension m in a finite dimensional vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Say $U$ is a vector space of dimension $n$ over $\mathbb{F}$, if $\mathbb{F}$ is finite we know there exists a bijection between the subspaces of dimension $n-m$ and $m$. Can this be generalized to any $\mathbb{F}$(keeping $dim\ U$ finite)?

-edit-

(Answer after help from comments)
Yes, there is.
We can map any $M$ with $dim\ M = m$ to its annihilator which has dimension $n-m$ (note that it is an injective map), do the same in $U'$ for its subspaces with dimension $n-m$ and use the fact that isomorphic finite dimensional vector spaces have the same number of $m$-dimensional subspaces(which is an easy exercise).

Comment: How do you know there is a bijection, in the finite case? Is it an explicit map that produces, from an $m$-dimensional subspace, an $n$-dimensional subspace? This would extend to infinite fields. A mere count of subspaces may not.

Comment: The finite case is an exercise in Halmo's book "Finite Dimensional Vector Spaces" and there is a sketch of a proof here: [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1271057/240879).

Comment: My point was that *if* you had a combinatorial bijection -- a way to produce a unique $(n - m)$-dimensional subspace from a given $m$-dimensional subspace (note the typo in my previous comment, whoops!) -- and not merely a count of subspaces, then the argument could likely be extended to infinite fields. Hence my previous question.

Comment: Do you want a 'natural' bijection or just any bijection ? Because if $U$ is finite-dimensional there is a bijection between $m$-dimensional subspaces of $U$ and $n-m$-dimensional spaces of $U^{*}$ (to each space associate it's annihilator) and you can go back from $U^{*}$ with an isomorphism $U^{*}\rightarrow U$.

Comment: Thanks! I was seeking any bijection. Now I understand Matt's answer.

Answer (score 2):

For finite dimensional vector spaces $V$ there is a natural bijection between subspaces of dimension $m$ of $V$ and subspaces of dimension $n-m$ of the dual of $V$. Given a subspace $A$ of dimension $m$, the corresponding subspace is the set of all linear functionals that vanish on $A$.

Edit: to incorporate Slade's comment and finish the story, if we have a nondegenerate bilinear form on $V$, not necessarily an inner product because this works over a completely general field, this gives us an isomorphism with $V^{\ast}$ and hence the bijection we seek.

Comment: But to map this back to $V$ you need something like an inner product because there is no natural isomorphism between $V$ and $V^*$.

Comment: @lhf an inner product is not necessary, a fixed basis would be sufficient.

Comment: yes, you're right.

Comment: There is a canonical inner product associated to a basis, but there is no canonical basis associated to an inner product.  So technically, it's more strict to ask for a basis than to ask for an inner product, which is equivalent to asking for an isomorphism $V\to V^\ast$.

Comment: @Slade there's no such thing as an inner product over a general field.

Comment: @MattSamuel You're right, I mean non-degenerate bilinear form.  lhf said that you need "something like an inner product", and, indeed, an isomorphism $V\to V^\ast$ is equivalent to a non-degenerate bilinear form on $V$.

Answer (score 1):

If the vector space has an inner product, then every subspace has a unique orthogonal complement, and that gives you the bijection you seek.

So the problem is: for which fields can one define an inner product for vector spaces of that field?

The easy answer is $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$.

In general, you need an ordered field, such as a subfield of $\mathbb R$.

I don't know what would be the analogue of $\mathbb C$ for a general ordered field.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6701/definition-of-inner-product-for-vector-spaces-over-arbitrary-fields.